# Google Chrome not responding on Lion

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, google-chrome

I have this irritating issue with the latest version of Chrome on my Air running Lion.

At least once a day it ceases to work. It doesnt freeze or crash, it just will not search or go to any sites. If I enter a URL into the browser and hit enter nothing happens. I have to completely quite the program and start again.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: Btw does quitting all the Chrome subprocesses (Chrome's main process will automatically restart them) temporary fix the issue?